# Add CSS tilemap to canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I'm creating my own CSS tilemap. The tilemap is 5x5, and will be 1000x1000px in size.

I would like to add it to a 500x500px canvas element so that only 1/2 the map is shown. I have a camera function that center the player to the canvas and move the tilemap relative to the player.

[image]

Goal: Put CSS Tilemap as a background in the HTML5 canvas (even though CSS tilemap is larger than canvas, there should be no overlap)

[image]

Given map array

```
var mapArray = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0 ,0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0 ,0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0 ,0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0 ,0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1 ,0]
];
```

I draw my map as such:

```
    function drawMap() {
        for (var i = 0; i < mapArray.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < mapArray[i].length; j++) {
                if (parseInt(mapArray[i][j]) == 0) {
                    $('#mapContainer').append('<div class="grass"></div>');
                }
                if (parseInt(mapArray[i][j]) == 1) {
                    $('#mapContainer').append('<div class="dirt"></div>');      
                }
            }
        }   
    }
```

CSS: I've tried appending the element directly to the HTML, and used `z-index: -1` to perhaps push the tilemap to the background, but that didn't work.

```
#mapContainer {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    outline: 1px solid black;
    z-index: -1;
}

.grass {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
    z-index: -1;
}

.dirt {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background-color: tan;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

How can I add the `#mapContainer` element to the canvas? I am using createJS, so I tried doing this:

```
function createWorld() {
    world = new createjs.Container();   
    var htmlElement = document.createElement('div');
    htmlElement.id = 'mapContainer';
    var domElement = new createjs.DOMElement(htmlElement);
    world.addChild(domElement);
    stage.addChild(world);  
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are spawning a div to contain a background image for every tile, you want the browser to render that behind your canvas (with the canvas translucent)?

I've done the divs-for-tiles before and I recommend against it. However, you should be able to achieve what your asking.

- the canvas has the style `background: transparent;` or `<canvas-element>.style.background = 'transparent';`.
- the canvas should be on top of the texture divs. I would recommend just making sure the canvas element occurs after the texture elements in the DOM tree / HTML, But if thats not easy `z-index` styles can take care of that too. I've never used negative z-indices's but they should work.

I would recommend doing the tile set rendering within the canvas. I've scaffolded soemthing like that together a long time ago. Your welcome to reuse any code from this old project: http://thorsummoner.github.io/old-html-tabletop-test/ source: https://github.com/thorsummoner/old-html-tabletop-test/blob/master/index.html

Comment: why do you recommend against using css and using tile set rendering instead?

Comment: also, where did you get those tiles from? Could you perhaps spend a bit of time walking me through that github code? (I really appreciate you sharing it with me btw)

Comment: Its been a long time since I've looked at that code, the function 'processmapfile' turned a png's composite colors red-green-blue into a sprie-map's tile x-y, coordinates, something like that.

Comment: `processmapfile` turned a png's composite colors red-green-blue into a sprie-map or tile-map's tile x-y indices's.

`init_render` did a loop that drew the cropped tile from the tile-map onto the screen.

Reading from my source won't be so great, but I think there should be snippets in there that can set you ahead by a ways. I advise you try to rewrite the things I did in your own way.